# Emulate a callback to the jQuery offset function?

Tags: jquery, callback, offset

I'm positioning a DIV using the jQuery `offset()` function. To avoid having the DIV flash in the incorrect position, I'm hiding the DIV prior to the positioning and then showing the DIV again afterwards. However, there is a synchronization issue and on some platforms (e.g. iPhone) I can still see the flash. What's the best way to emulate a callback function for the `offset()` function?

```
$('div').hide();
y = Math.round(($(window).height() - $('div').outerHeight())/2);
$('div').offset({top : y});
$('div').fadeIn();
```

**EDIT**

Also, it is important that this element is still visible if JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: Ah, that will be harder to answer then. Are you hiding the element in a `ready` or `pageinit` handler, or are you doing that from a `<script>` element at the end of your `<body>`?

Comment: All of this code is currently placed within a `$(document).ready()` call at the end of the `<body>`

Comment: Try getting rid of the `ready()` call. At the end of your `<body>` element, everything that occurs before in the DOM tree should be available (baring some properties of images and other asynchronous content). A "raw" script *may* run before `domready` is triggered, and the flashing effect *might* be avoided in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could render your `<div>` element outside of the viewport from the get-go, then reposition it right before hiding it and proceed to set its offset and fade it in:

#### CSS:

```
.outside-viewport {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000px;
}
```

#### Javascript:

```
var $div = $("div.outside-viewport");
$div.css({
    position: "relative",
    left: "0px"
}).hide().offset({
    top: ($(window).height() - $div.outerHeight()) / 2
}).fadeIn();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That's similar to something else I was thinking of doing (setting `display:none` in the CSS) but this is a critical element that shouldn't rely on JavaScript to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

The odd thing with jQuery's offsets in this case is that the above suggestion by Frederic is the only one that effectively restores the original left offset of the element. jQuery has some problems with hidden elements and offsets. For example, if you use `position: static`, which is correct according to the CSS specs, the left offset will be still at -10000 pixels, though the element will be visible in the viewport. Just a note. I hope it'll be useful. :-)